# Facebook marks my website as spam

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

I can't share my website on Facebook anywhere. Facebook marks it as spam. The [Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) also doesn't run and says that my website does not meet the community standards.I have tried reporting Facebook and saying that it is not a spam.

[image]

Comment: See also [Community Standards for spam](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/spam)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [official answer](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10154278072908220&answer_id=10154281335208220&rdrhc):

> You might try running your website through the Facebook Debugger:
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?ref=u2u
>
> This tool was built to help to identify any errors that Facebook is reading from your website, and help provide information on what needs to be fixed to unblock your link.
>
> From there, you can get help from your developers team or from the Facebook Developers team to make your website compliant and help our systems detect it as safe. Click the link below and select "Get Started" to open a support ticket with the Facebook Developers team (this option may not be available for all websites):
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/?ref=u2u

<sup><sup>Source</sup></sup>

Comment: I can't run the tool. it says that my website does not meet the community standards

Comment: Then make changes whatever is required.. without passing the community standard you will not able to pass.